# Versione femminile di alcuni nomi/aggettivi come "invasore"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Ieri mentre leggevo un testo in inglese ho trovato "the invading army". Non volendo usare *esercito* ("l'esercito invasore" sarebbe la traduzione più immediata) ma *orda* per ragioni di contesto (vedi commenti), come potrei traslare al femminile l'aggettivo?

Giacché non credo (potrei sbagliarmi) che "invasrice" esista, mi chiedo se esiste però un modo per rendere l'aggettivo al femminile senza usare una perifrasi per esprimere il concetto.

Chi mi aiuta?

Comment: *Armata* per *esercito* già non mi sembra granché, essendo un chiaro anglicismo. Se proprio vuoi, *armata di invasione*.

Comment: @egreg Si, appunto. Il contesto era quello dell'ondata dei cosiddetti "barbari" che invadono un posto, non si trattava di un "esercito" militarmente attrezzato e organizzato.

Comment: Allora *orda* o qualcos'altro, perché un'armata è certamente organizzata.

Comment: ...o francesismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Penso tu possa tradurre come:

> - L'invasione armata o l'armata che invade.

Il femminile  di invasore e' [invaditrice](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=invasore), ma non e' di uso comune.

Comment: Vale la pena di ricordare la regola generale: quando il sostantivo maschile finisce in *-tore* (in questo caso, "invasore" si comporta come "invaditore"), si sostituisce con *-trice* ("invaditrice").

Answer (score 2):

> L'armata che invade

La versione

> L'armata invadente

Benché corretta, è poco utilizzata nel parlato moderno.

Se potessi aggiungere maggiore contesto della frase che stai cercando di tradurre potrebbe essere più semplice comprenderne il significato.

Comment: Grazie mille e benvenuto sul sito! In realtà è chiaro che la traduzione è quella, la domanda voleva provocare più in generale una discussione su questi aggettivi che non hanno, almeno a livello comune, un femminile così chiaro.

Comment: Non penso che 'invadente' sia appropriato nel contesto. Si usa comunemente col significato di 'indiscreto' . Nel senso di invadere (un territorio ad esempio) perso sia quantomeno insolito.